# Vim ":set cindent" filters commas from the document

Tags: vim, documents, characters, indentation

With or without a specific document language, whenever "cindent" is set on vim, no comma can be typed or even pasted on the document.

I got a "non-us-standard" keyboard (pt-latin).

Comment: Does this still happen when Vim is invoked as: `vim -u NONE -U NONE --noplugin -N -c 'set cindent'`

Comment: No. It doesn't happens when i invoke that way. Can you tell me whats wrong?

Comment: Basically what that command does is disable *everything* else, and sets 'cindent' on.  What it means is that you probably have something in your startup files (vimrc, etc.) or plugins that is interfering.

Comment: There was a problem on the .vimrc, cinkeys were by mistake including the comma. Sort of duplicate of this one: http://askubuntu.com/questions/10662/comma-input-is-missing-in-vim-insert-mode